# Error: "El método de comparación infringe su contrato general."

Tags: javascript

Este error me aparece al correr un código, que sin hacer ningún cambio, dejó de funcionar.

El error hace referencia al ordenamiento de una matriz mostrado en las siguiente lineas de mi código:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var MATRIZ_INFO = [];
    MATRIZ_INFO = sheet.getRange(5, 1, 32, 4).getValues();

//ordeno la nueva matriz, respecto a los cambios  
MATRIZ_INFO.sort(function (a,b) {
    if (a[4] < b[4]) return  1;
    else if (a[4] > b[4]) return -1;
    else return 0;
})
```

Quisiera saber si saben el motivo de este error o alguna posible solución!

Aparte consulto si existe otro método de ordenamiento para matrices o vectores.

Comment: podrías añadir la definición de las variables `sheet`, `Fila_inicial`, `Col_cambios` ... Tambien ayudaría saber si estas usando alguna libreria en concreto

Comment: `MATRIZ_INFO` es un `Array`? que navegador estas usando? que bibliotecas podrian haber sobreescrito la funcionadad de `sort()`?

Comment: Que tal Angel, el navegador que uso es Chrome. Ya declaré las variables solicitadas.  MATRIZ_INFO es una matriz y no estoy usando ninguna librería ni biblioteca.